# BeautifulSoup find_all returns just first element

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some data. My code is below.

```
        import time
        from selenium import webdriver
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
        from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
        from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
        from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
        import re
        import pandas as pd
        
        
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/tmarkac/source/repos/chromedriver.exe')
        team_name = 'G.Paterno/M.Tona'
        
        u =f'https://superbet.pl/wyszukaj?query={team_name}'
        
        
        url = driver.get(u)
        driver.maximize_window()
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]').click()
        time.sleep(1)
        
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
        time.sleep(5)
expand = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'icon.icon--md.event-row__expanded-market-icon.icon-chevron_down')
        
        exp_clicks = 0
        for i in expand:
            i.click()
            time.sleep(0.5)
            exp_clicks +=1
        time.sleep(3)
        
        markets = []
    market_container = soup.find('div', class_= 'event-row__expanded-markets')
    
    markets_html = market_container.find_all('div', class_='event-row__expanded-market')
```

I just don't understand why this line: `market_html = soup.find_all('div', class_= 'event-row__expanded-market')` returns only 1st element. Furthermore, I actually got all elements with this a few times after which something changed, and could only get the 1st element. pretty sure elements are there as I can see them in the DOM.
Please note this line: `team_name = 'G.Paterno/M.Tona'` will be an input for looking up this event on page. Most likely when you will be looking at this code this event will be over so please copy/paste any event team/player name in the `team_name` variable to get the code working. Thank you.

Comment: I just noticed this code works fine only the first time I run it. So if I paste the team name in the team_name variable and run it it will scrape everything I need. If I re-run the code it will just pick get 1st element in this line:  market_html = soup.find_all('div', class_= 'event-row__expanded-market'). Not sure why it is behaving this way.

Comment: Your code snippet is not reproducible: include a valid URL, please, or a list with valid queries/team names.

Comment: Hi Barry, possibly I didn't explained very well. So team_name is the query. And for team_name just copy/paste what ever team you find on site...team_name can be picked up from this url: https://superbet.pl/zaklady-bukmacherskie/live

Comment: Ok. Now, what are you after on that page? You did not include your full code. Where is `expand` defined, before clicking on it? Also, why use BeautifulSoup, when the page is already parsed by selenium, and you already have access to elements?

Comment: I added expand line in the original post. So the logic is to get the URL by query->open the page->get all markets to be expanded(by default only top 3 markets are expanded). Then I tried grabbing the part of HTML which contains all the markets and its info in the market_container variable and then from that variable I tried grabbing individual market HTML in markets_html variable and this is where I get in trouble as I get only HTML for 1st market.

Comment: I think something changes after preforming clicks on markets to get them expanded, but I still don't know how to solve it